# Is there a python binding for Undo/Redo?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm on a mac, and i can press `CMD+Z` to undo, `SHIFT+CMD+Z` to redo.

Is there a way to trigger these in the python console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

```
bpy.ops.ed.undo()
bpy.ops.ed.redo()
```

[More operators of that kind here: https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.ops.ed.html?highlight=undo#bpy.ops.ed.undo_redo](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.ops.ed.html?highlight=undo#bpy.ops.ed.undo_redo)

Comment: Thanks, when I clicked undo, the console at the top wouldn't output that as an operation. so i figured they didn't exist haha.

Comment: That console does not log quite some operators, so it is always a good idea to check the API document. Fortunately, the naming is quite good there.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can add a function that is called back before and or after on which to do some further clean up? and how that's done. [maybe it's another question I suppose.]